# how to get the 5 tuples with the highest values, from the following vector?

Tags: python, numpy

I am performing an experiment using gensim. I am using the lda model to obtain a vector of probabilities that looks like this:

```
[(0, 0.01666666666666804), (1, 0.01666666666666982), (2, 0.01666666666667857), 
 (3, 0.016666666666667104), (4, 0.016666666666668519), (5, 0.01666666666666838), 
 (6, 0.016666666666681464), (7, 0.016666666666669494), (8, 0.016666666666669269), 
 (9, 0.016666666666667069), (10, 0.016666666668398125), (11, 0.016666666666666666), 
 (12, 0.51666666666481131), (13, 0.01666666666668485), (14, 0.01666666666666948), 
 (15, 0.016666666666667097), (16, 0.016666666666666666), (17, 0.016666666666666767), 
 (18, 0.016666666666667922), (19, 0.016666666666678695), (20, 0.016666666666667683), 
 (21, 0.016666666666677307), (22, 0.016666666666669522), (23, 0.016666666666675913), 
 (24, 0.016666666666670923), (25, 0.016666666666667409), (26, 0.016666666666680405), 
 (27, 0.016666666666666666), (28, 0.0166666666666705), (29, 0.016666666666668353)]
```

It is a list composed of tuples,the first component of the tuple is the topic and the second the probability:

```
(topic, probability)
```

I would like to obtain the 5 topics with the highest probabilities in a list of tuples, as follows:

```
max = [(topicN, probability),...]
```

I tried first transforming this tuple in a numpy structure as follows:

```
vector = lda[ques_vec]
print(vector)
types = numpy.dtype('int,float')
data = numpy.array(vector,dtype=types)
print(data)
```

However I am not sure how to order this structure to get the list of the five tuples with the highest probabilities so I would like to appreciate support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The built-in `heapq` module contains an [`nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) function:

```
from heapq import nlargest
from operator import itemgetter

>>> nlargest(5, vector, key=itemgetter(1))  # get the 5 largest values based on the second item in each tuple
[(12, 0.5166666666648113), (10, 0.016666666668398125), (13, 0.01666666666668485), (6, 0.016666666666681464), (26, 0.016666666666680405)]
```

or you could use reversed sorted with slicing:

```
>>> sorted(vec, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:5]
[(12, 0.5166666666648113), (10, 0.016666666668398125), (13, 0.01666666666668485), (6, 0.016666666666681464), (26, 0.016666666666680405)]
```

However both approaches don't require `numpy`.

---

It's also possible using numpy, however the approach I could come up with requires some intermediate steps:

```
>>> types = np.dtype('int, float')
>>> data = np.array(vector, dtype=types)
>>> np.sort(data, order='f1')[-5:][::-1]
array([(12, 0.5166666666648113), (10, 0.016666666668398125),
       (13, 0.01666666666668485), (6, 0.016666666666681464),
       (26, 0.016666666666680405)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

This uses [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html#numpy.sort) based on the second column (`order='f1'`), then takes the 5 last items (numpy only supports sorting from low to high) `[-5:]` and finally reverses the remaining items (`[::-1]`).

A word of caution with `np.sort`: By default it uses a non-stable sorting algorithm (Quicksort). So if you expect several values with the same probability you may want a stable sorting, then you should specify `kind='mergesort'`.

There is another way using numpy that does not require a full sort: [`np.partition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html#numpy-partition):

```
>>> types = np.dtype('int, float')
>>> data = np.array(vector, dtype=types)
>>> np.partition(data, -5, order='f1')[-5:][::-1]
array([(12, 0.5166666666648113), (10, 0.016666666668398125),
       (13, 0.01666666666668485), (6, 0.016666666666681464),
       (26, 0.016666666666680405)], 
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<f8')])
```

However `partition` supports no stable algorithm so it may be faster but it's definetly less flexible.